# How to fetch latest entry in a related table while making sure the query is optimized

Tags: mysql, django, query-optimization, greatest-n-per-group, django-serializer

I have two models in consideration. RV_Offers and RV_Details. Each offer can have multiple details i.e. I have a foreignkey relationship field in RV_Details table.

Here is my view:

```
rv_offers_queryset = RV_Offers.objects.all().select_related('vendor').prefetch_related('details')
details_queryset = RV_Details.objects.all().select_related('rv_offer')

title = Subquery(details_queryset.filter(
                rv_offer=OuterRef("id"),
            ).order_by("-created_at").values("original_title")[:1])

offers_queryset = rv_offers_queryset.annotate(
                title=title).filter(django_query)
            offers = RVOffersSerializer(offers_queryset, many=True).data
            return Response({'result': offers}, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

As can be seen, I am passing the offers queryset to the serializer.
Now, here is my serializer:

```
class RVOffersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    details = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    vendor = VendorSerializer()

    def get_details(self, obj):
        queryset = RV_Details.objects.all().select_related('rv_offer')
        queryset = queryset.filter(rv_offer=obj.id).latest('created_at')
        return RVDetailsSerializer(queryset).data

    class Meta:
        model = RV_Offers
        fields = '__all__'
```

If you look at the get_details method, I am trying to fetch the latest detail that belongs to an offer. My problem is, even though I am using select_related to optimize the query, the results are still extremely slow, In fact, I am using django debug toolbar to inspect the query and apparently select_related seems to have no effect.
What am I doing wrong or how else can I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to reduce the number of queries being hit on the db:

```
def get_details(self, obj):
    details = obj.details.last()
    return RVDetailsSerializer(details).data
```

I was able to reduce the number of queries from 45 to 4 using this.
This is because in the view, I had already used select_related to make the queryset, which in turn is being used here using obj.